# RESOLVE: Fastapi upload large file using stream

Tags: python, fastapi, multipartform-data

I'm trying to create an endpoint that allows me to download a large file using a stream.
But I want to get chunks of the file with a size specified as (CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 20).
Furthermore, I only want the binary data of the file in my chunks.

Example:

```py
async for chunk in request.stream():
    print(chunk)
```

current result:

```bash
b'--8af8cd2412f5572588d978d2a7c51016\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="toto.txt"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n'
b'this is my file data! (Can be huge data)\r\n--8af8cd2412f5572588d978d2a7c51016--\r\n'
```

Result that i want (only the binary data of my file):

```bash
b'this is my file data! (Can be huge data)'
# or for large file
b'...' * 999
```

If the community can help me, that would be very kind.

I tried several things like:

- streaming_form_data: but i don't need to create the file on my hard drive, i saw i could use stuff with TargetValue but it didn't work (for me).
- I even tried to make my own form data parser, but it doesn't work at all.

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.post("/uploads/stream")
async def upload_stream(request: Request):
    filename = request.headers.get('file')
    boundary = request.headers.get('content-type').split("boundary=")[1].encode("utf-8")
    content_type = request.headers.get('content-type').encode("utf-8")

    ender = b"\r\n--" + boundary + b"--\r\n"
    starter = b"--" + boundary + b"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + filename.encode("utf-8") + b"\"\r\nContent-Type: " + content_type + b"\r\n\r\n"
    is_file = False

    async for chunk in request.stream():
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            continue

        if starter in chunk:
            print("starter found")
            print(chunk.split(starter)[1])
            is_file = True

        if ender in chunk:
            print("ender found")
            print(chunk.split(ender)[0])
            is_file = False

        if is_file:
            pass # todo: do stuff with the chunk here


    return {"file": filename}
```

---

**RESOLVE**:

For this solution, I use python multipart:
`pip install python-multipart`

I've optimized the callback with thread pool and collector and a CHUNK_SIZE, but feel free to update my code, or let me know if I've made any mistakes.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from multipart import MultipartParser
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse


CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 20


class UploadFileByStream:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = None
        self.bytes_received = None
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
        self.results = []
        self.futures = []

    def on_part_begin(self):
        self.buffer = b""
        self.bytes_received = 0

    def on_part_data(self, data, start, end):
        self.buffer += data[start:end]
        self.bytes_received += end - start

        if self.bytes_received >= CHUNK_SIZE:
            self.send_buffer()

    def on_part_end(self):
        if self.buffer:
            self.send_buffer()

    def send_buffer(self):
        future = self.executor.submit(YOUR_FUNCTION, self.buffer)
        self.futures.append(future)

        self.buffer = b""
        self.bytes_received = 0

    def collect_result(self):
        for future in self.futures:
            try:
                result = future.result()
                self.results.extend(result)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error while processing chunk:", e)


@app.post("/test/upload")
async def upload_test(request: Request):
    filename = request.headers.get("file")
    content_type = request.headers.get("Content-Type")

    if not content_type or "boundary=" not in content_type:
        return JSONResponse(content="Invalid Content-Type header", status_code=400)

    _, boundary = content_type.split("boundary=")

    file = UploadFileByStream()

    callbacks = {
        'on_part_begin': file.on_part_begin,
        'on_part_data': file.on_part_data,
        'on_part_end': file.on_part_end,
    }

    parser = MultipartParser(boundary, callbacks)

    async for chunk in request.stream():
        parser.write(chunk)

    file.collect_result()

    return {"filename": filename}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything to support that built-in to Starlette/FastAPI - what you're seeing is the raw multipart encoding as the stream is served. Have you looked at something like https://github.com/siddhantgoel/streaming-form-data as an option? (referenced in https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/849)

Comment: Hi, @MatsLindh Yes, I looked at streaming-form-data and found things like [ValueTarget](https://streaming-form-data.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#valuetarget) but when I tried it didn't work, the value is still empty And also i don't know if i can only keep the chunk in memory with ValueTarget. Perhaps you know of a framework where it's easier to do this?